# mean of triplicate measurments in 3 matrices

Tags: r, matrix, mean

I am having 3 matrices that store values from triplicate measurements and would like to take the mean of the 3 matrices.

So let's say the three matrices are:

```
m1<-t(matrix(c("text", 1:3), ncol=2, nrow=4))
m2<-t(matrix(c("text", 1:3), ncol=2, nrow=4))
m3<-t(matrix(c("text", 1:3), ncol=2, nrow=4))

> m1
     [,1]   [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "text" "1"  "2"  "3" 
[2,] "text" "1"  "2"  "3" 
> m2
     [,1]   [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "text" "1"  "2"  "3" 
[2,] "text" "1"  "2"  "3" 
> m3
     [,1]   [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "text" "1"  "2"  "3" 
[2,] "text" "1"  "2"  "3"
```

I would like to have this for every position of the matrices:

```
mean(m1[i,j], m2[i,j], m2[i,j])
```

So I tried it with 2 for loops:

```
for(i in ncol(m1)){
  for(j in nrow(m1)){
    means[i,j]<-mean(m1[i,j], m2[i,j], m2[i,j])
  }
```

which obviously doesn't work

The text in the first column isn't an issue if NA is returned.

Anyone could help me please?
Thanks!

Comment: You asked for `mean` in this post and I provided that.  What is the problem in my code?

Answer (score 1):

We can place it in a `list`, convert to numeric and use `Reduce`

```
lst <- lapply(list(m1[, -1], m2[,-1], m3[, -1]), as.numeric)
Reduce(`+`,lst)/length(lst)
```

If there are many matrices starting with 'm', we can use `mget`

```
lst <- lapply(mget(paste0("m", 1:3)), function(x) as.numeric(x[,-1]))
```

and then do the `Reduce` step.

Comment: But how will this calculate the mean?

Comment: @KevinRoth  It does elementwise sum and when we divide by 3 i.e. number of matrices, we get the mean

Comment: appologies, I meant the median, not the mean. Stupid me

Comment: @KevinRoth Your whole post is about `mean`.  I answered the question you posted.